# Very basic trig question: how to calculate an angle given a slope (an angle from a ratio of sides)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to write a very basic trig primer, from scratch.
I [asked](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/24860/how-to-teach-relationship-between-slopes-and-angles/) a basic question on Mathematics Educators, but they suggest to ask here. Here it is.

Say I discuss slopes (say, the slope of a line through the origin), and wish to give the 'right' hints on how the slope of a line is related to the angle of the line with the $x$-axis.

It would be nice to show how to calculate the angle, given the slope. I am looking for easy examples, say for lines with slopes 1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...; or any suitable family of lines.

I am not completely sure, but my question seems to be something like: how do I design an algorithm (and/or a geometric construction) to determine the angle from the slope (i.e,  from the ratio of sides). It would fine and interesting a construction which returns successive approximations to the precise value.

In the picture, angle measures are given by the LaTeX package tkz-euclide. I would like to have a way to show how they are calculated.

[image]

Sorry to be quite vague.

Comment: Which ratio ? Height over horizontal length or height over length ?

Comment: I mean rise/run

Comment: Doing a drawing is always a good tip in a trig exercise...

Comment: The rise over the run (slope) is the tangent of the angle the line makes with the $x$-axis.

Comment: @JohnDouma  Actually, what I am looking for is  $arctan()$. My primer should be a way to introduce trig functions by the correct insights, so a definition of arctan() (or its table of values) is not to be implied or pre-assumed.

Comment: Assuming that $~\displaystyle\frac{y}{x} ~$ is a rational number, the expression for $~\displaystyle \text{Arctan}\left[\frac{y}{x}\right] ~$ generally won't be a *nice* expression in either degrees {$(360^\circ) = 1$ revolution} or radians {$(2\pi) = 1$ revolution}.  There is a power sum expression for the Arctan function.  However, in my opinion, this expression is well beyond what you would want to put in a trig *primer*.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I am thinking along similar line. Are there set of rational numbers for which the expression could be decently nice?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no there are not.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to compute the slope for any angle without trigonometric functions.

A critical step is to establish the "angle addition" formula in term of slopes

$$\text{slope}(\theta+\phi)=\frac{\text{slope}(\theta)+\text{slope}(\phi)}{1-\text{slope}(\theta)\,\text{slope}(\phi)}.$$

This can be done by studying the similarities in this figure and evaluating the orange run/rise from those of the blue and green triangles:

[image]

From this, you get the double angle formula

$$\text{slope}(2\theta)=\frac{2\text{ slope}(\theta)}{1-\text{slope}^2(\theta)}$$

and by inversion,

$$\text{slope}\left(\frac\theta2\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\text{slope}^2(\theta)+1}-1}{\text{slope}(\theta)}.$$

In particular, from the obvious $\text{slope(45°)}=1$, you draw $\text{slope(22.5°)}=\sqrt2-1$ and other fractions.

Finally, as any number can be written as a sum of positive and negative powers of $2$, you can compute the slope corresponding to any angle.

---

The plot below was obtained by computing the slopes for all angles multiple of $1/64^{\text{th}}$ of a right angle. One can understand that also linear interpolation can be used to approximate the angles from the slopes.

[image]

Comment: Nice response.  Unfortunately, the OP wants to determine the angle from the slope, rather than vice-versa.  Personally, I don't think that there is a suitable approach for what the OP wants, in a trig *primer*.

Comment: @user2661923: the inverse relation can be obtained by dichotomic search, at least in principle, and the computation is not meant to be actually performed. Though it is worth to notice that the above method is an embodiment of the CORDIC algorithm, effectively used in some calculators to evaluate the trigonometric functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Thanks, I have my homework! "the inverse relation can be obtained by dichotomic search": hint or reference?

Comment: @mario: $\text{slope}(22.5°)=0.414\cdots $ and $\text{slope}(45°)=1\cdots$. So if you want the angle for the slope $0.5$, compute the slope for angle $22.5°+11.25°$, giving $0.668\cdots$ and you know that the searched angle is in $(22.5°,33.75°)$. Continue to narrow down the interval. Tedious but works in theory.

Comment: @YvesDaoust A comment on the fly from ignorance, is this somehow related to Taylor series too?

Comment: @mario: no, I would not say that.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. Do you have a reference for your answer? Do I find it in some classic textbook? (which one?)

Comment: @mario: the tangent addition formula is found everywhere. The explanation about constructing any angle, nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

The angle the line of slope $m$ makes with the $x$-axis is $\arctan(m)$.  If you want to approximate this, you can use the Taylor series for $\arctan x$:

$$\phi = m - \frac{m^3}{3}+\frac{m^5}{5}-\frac{m^7}{7}+\cdots$$

Use as many terms as you need for the accuracy you want.  This gives the answer in radians, so you'll have to multiply by $180/\pi$ for degrees.  The series converges slowly, so you'll need a lot of terms. There are more efficient approximations for $\arctan x$, but they're more complicated.

Comment: The issue is whether this is what you would want to put in a trig *primer*.

Comment: @user2661923 The issue is whether from the theory of Taylor series (and its justification) I may extract  simple cases/examples which help to show what is going on.

Comment: Personally, I have always assumed that the study of Trigonometry (re Trig primer) comes well ahead of Real Analysis (AKA Calculus).  Given that, I don't think that any mention of or dependency on Taylor series is appropriate for a Trig *primer*.

Comment: @user2661923  The theory of Taylor series isn't required.  Mention of arctan is not required.   You can tell the students that here's a way (a 5th-grade way) to calculate the number they want.

Comment: @B.Goddard  $$arctan(m) = m - \frac{m^3}{3}+\frac{m^5}{5}-\frac{m^7}{7}+\cdots$$ Is there a simple geometrical argument to show that it has to be so?

Comment: To B. Goddard : nice rebuttal.  To @mario: The only analytical demonstration that I know of involves Calculus.  Namely that the derivative of Arctan$(x)$ is $$\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \cdots - \cdots ~: ~|x| < 1.$$  The formula given in B. Goddard's last comment then comes from integrating  $$1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \cdots - \cdots.$$  Also, it should be emphasized that this assumes that the **domain** of the Arctan function is Real numbers, rather than angles.  So, the student would have to learn that the **dimensionless** number $(\pi/4)$ (for example), relates to $45^\circ$.

Comment: @mario Personally, I again question this approach in a Trig primer, because the student is going to have serious trouble regarding the domain of the Arctan function to be (dimensionless) Real numbers, rather than angles.  This conversion of the domain of trig functions is a very artificial  contrivance that was created solely to facilitate the solutions to certain Real Analysis (AKA Calculus) problems.  The Trig primer student will not relate to this at all.

Comment: @user2661923  I'll think about your objections.  I am trying to think in (what I think are) basic geometry terms, and to check what I may justify accordingly. I have my homework, I'll see what I am able to get to. Thanks

Comment: I am looking at a history of math [paper by Ranjan Roy](http://users.uoa.gr/~apgiannop/Sources/Roy-pi.pdf) on how people got to the formula for $arctan()$. Would it be possible to recast those earlier arguments  in modern term (and typography), but with a minimun of calculus? Also, any further reference on the same topic is welcome.